# geom_rect and NULL

Tags: r, null, ggplot2

I've been looking at the geom_rect example in section 5.10 of the
ggplot2 book and don't understand the purpose of the NULL's in the `aes`
function.  For example, using the `mpg` data:

```
g = ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) + geom_point()

#Produces a plot with a transparent filled region
g + geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL), alpha=0.1,xmin=5, xmax=7, ymin=10,
ymax=45, fill="blue")

#Solid filled region (v0.9) or nothing in v0.8
g + geom_rect(alpha=0.1,xmin=5, xmax=7, ymin=10, ymax=45, fill="blue")
```

My understanding is that the NULL's are resetting the x & y mapping,
but I don't see why this should affect the transparency.

Comment: Your second example doesn't produce a rectangle at all for me. But `geom_rect` has always seemed like voodoo to me (the only way I can get it to work reliably is to always pass it its own data frame).

Comment: @joran: I'm using ggplot v0.9. I didn't think there would be a difference, sorry. Regardless, what is the `NULL` all about in the second command?

Comment: My understanding is the same as yours, namely that it is resetting the x and y aesthetics. But I also don't know why that would effect the alpha, sorry.

Comment: The reason why the specification matters is that multiple transparent rectangles stacked on top of each other will look solid - because you haven't reset the data, you get one rectangle for each row in mtcars.  You probably want to use `annotate` instead.

Comment: @hadley: does that mean that all geom's have all aesthetics, since x & y aren't listed under geom_rect? Also, would you make your comment an answer so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've just made Hadley's comment a community wiki answer*

> The reason why the specification matters is that multiple transparent
>   rectangles stacked on top of each other will look solid - because you
>   haven't reset the data, you get one rectangle for each row in mtcars.
>   You probably want to use annotate instead.